# Select specific data sets in PhpStorm using PHPunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, filter, phpunit, phpstorm

I am trying to run only one test data set for a test function and found [this instruction](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.examples.filter-patterns) in the PHPUnit manual.

Basically I understand that PHPUnit should be called with this input:

```
--filter '/::testMethod .*"my named data"/'
```

However, when I enter this in PhpStorm at the run configuration (see below):

[image]

it throws the following error:

> `/usr/bin/php /Users/<user_name>/Coding/Plugins_and_Frameworks/phpunit-5.7.4.phar --filter '/::testTax .*ints16/' --configuration /Users/<user_name>/Coding/phpunit/phpunit.xml TDD\Test\ReceiptTest /Users/matthiaslang/Coding/phpunit/tests/ReceiptTest.php --teamcity`
>
> Testing started at 14:30 ...
>     Cannot open file ".*ints16/'.php".
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Here is the test function:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideTax
 */
public function testTax ($input, $expected)
{
    $actual = $this->receipt->tax($input);
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual, "The calculated tax for $input should be $expected but is $actual.");
}

public function provideTax () {
    $values = [
                "ints16" => [10, 1],
                [100, 10],
                [200, 20],
                [-100, -10]
                ];
    return $values;
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: If the configuration works directly in the command line, then you have to escape something in PHPStorm input field. Just an idea.

Comment: And why are `//` in the path in the error message, it is not normal.

Comment: Thing the issue is that you have `/Users/matthiaslang/Coding/phpunit/tests/ReceiptTest.php` but you have to use `/Users/matthiaslang/Coding/phpunit/tests/ReceiptTest` <- wihtout `.php`

Comment: You should point you notice to this part `Cannot open file ".*ints16/'.php".` And ask youself why it trys to open `.*ints16/'` as file with the extention `.php`. im out.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the .php removed from there? So far this was generated automatically. When I remove the .php in menu from the screenshot above it of course does not find the file anymore.

Comment: How about to use `Defined in the configuration file` and only add needed stuff in PHPStorm, do the rest with phpunit & xml (config). Note: Im working with phpunit & phpstrom, but not used them together. So i only try to give hints here.

Comment: Did you notice that here `--filter '/::testTax .*ints16/'` the double-quots are missing, that are seen in the PHPstrom field but not in the error message? Why are the removed? Maybe escape them `\"`

Comment: Hi, I tried the string with escape characters and without e.g. like this: --filter '/::testTax .*\"Below_100\"/'
However, that resulted in similar errors.
I thought it would be nice to use PHPUnit directly from PHPStorm and so far had no problems executing everything from PHPStorm but now I am having second thoughts.  Would you add the filter directly to the xml file just run PHPUnit from the command line with these parameters?

Comment: Mmh, so actual it is not possible to say if phpstrom or phpunti creates the error. I have no more ideas.

Comment: Just for testing everthing `--filter '/::testMethod .*#0$/'` test the index version of the filter without `"` https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html and maybe if one set has a name, all other must have a name too?!?

Comment: After countless back and forth, here is filter string that works in PHPStorm: 
--filter "testTax@ints16"
Thx for your help @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: Fine........................:-)